# wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) with Resque Worker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, resque

I understand the self.perform method needs two arguments and I am passing them in. I can assure you the instance variables have values because I have checked. What can you see am I doing wrong?

Controller:

```
Resque.enqueue_to(:high, SendInvitationEmail, user_token: @user.token, invitee_token: @invitee.token)
```

Worker:

```
class SendInvitationEmail
  def self.perform(user_token, invitee_token)
      Frontend::UserManagementMailer.invitation_email(user_token, invitee_token)
  end
end
```

Error:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 2) line 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you're passing arguments to `enqueue_to` as keyword arguments or a `Hash`.

Instead, remove the keys and pass the arguments as such.

```
Resque.enqueue_to(:high, SendInvitationEmail, @user.token, @invitee.token)
```

Or you could modify the method signature of perform to take in a hash or keyword arguments as

```
class SendInvitationEmail
  def self.perform(user_token:, invitee_token:)
      Frontend::UserManagementMailer.invitation_email(user_token, invitee_token)
  end
end
```